# Import big xls file into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, spreadsheet, xls

I want to import big **xlsx** ( spreadsheet file ) into mysql database.
I did it before by phpmyadmin , but this file is too big ( 205000 rows ).

so when I wanna do it by phpmyadmin,it has taken a long time and wasn't done.

what is best and fast way to import it to mysql database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using the `LOAD DATA` command in MySQL:
http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html

> ```
> Save your Excel data as a csv file (In Excel 2007 using Save As)
> Check the saved file using a text editor such as Notepad to see what it actually looks like, i.e. what delimiter was used etc.
> Start the MySQL Command Prompt (I usually do this from the MySQL Query Browser – Tools – MySQL Command Line Client to avoid having to enter username and password etc.)
> Enter this command:
> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘C:\\temp\\yourfile.csv’ INTO TABLE database.table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘;’ ENCLOSED BY ‘”‘ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\r\n’ (field1, field2);
> [Edit: Make sure to check your single quotes (') and double quotes (") if you copy and paste this code]
> Done!
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Navicat MySQL. I've done this with 250MB+ xlsx file and Navicat handle it flawlessly without breaking a sweat.

Just make sure your MySQL is configured to be able to receive large amount of data by changing the `max_allowed_packet` option in your `my.ini` to a larger amount, say, 128M.

Answer (score 0):

Toad for MySQL (Freeware) would be another alternative.